# django forms - Access fields of a foreign key

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I'd like to create a modelform from a model A which has a foreign key to a model B :

```
class A(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(...)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    c = models.CharField(...)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField(...)
    b = models.CharField(...)
    c = models.BooleanField(...)
```

So I did this :

```
class AForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = A
```

But I only want some fields :

```
class AForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('a', 'b')
```

The problem is here, I don't want b to be a list of B objects, but I want the fields B.a and B.c (for instance). I tried "fields = ('a', 'b.a', 'b.c')" and "fields = ('a', 'b_*a', b*_c')" but fruitlessly.

So I came to [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets), but I didn't see anything to restrict the set of fields of the inline.

What should I do ? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I filter ForeignKey choices in a Django ModelForm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform)

Comment: from what I understood, this is more about filtering choices, which is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the inline fields like this (ofcourse you still need the form to validate, you could use javascript or default values to set gaps)

```
class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ["x", "y", "z"]

    #fk_name = "..."
    #max_num = 1
    #extra = 0
```

Comment: How do you use admin.TabularInline on ModelForms ?

Comment: docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

Comment: You can achieve the same with a factory, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559361/inline-formset-in-django-removing-certain-fields

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show proper text for 'B' in choice field, in your model `B` add `__unicode__` method and return string using fields of `B`,

eg.

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField(...)
    b = models.CharField(...)
    c = models.BooleanField(...)
    def __unicode__(self):
         return u''+str(self.a) + ':' + self.b
```

Answer (score 0):

`inlineformset_factory` accepts `form` argument, which is a modelform class for your "B" objects. So, defining a form class with `fields = ('a', 'b')` in `Meta` and passing it to the function should help.